# How do I create page transitions for my website

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, css-transitions

OK so I am a newbie PHP developer and have knowledge of HTML, CSS and JQuery but I a not too sure on how I would go about creating page transitions. I have found a great example and I would love for someone to point me in the right direction.

Example:[This is the site I got the page transitions from.](http://www.iuvo.si)

I'm not sure if this site is using JQuery or perhaps CSS with AJAX. Is there a JQuery library out there that will do what this example site can do?

Thank you in advance for helping or pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: study the source code to see how they do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use CSS and a little bit of Javascript.

I strongly recommend http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/07/a-collection-of-page-transitions/